# error when calling the webservice

Tags: c#, web-services, asmx

i am getting a list of pagepack assistant by calling a webservice. I have added the web reference.

```
using org.xerox.xde3.na.sdi.amiller_v_vista;
public org.xerox.xde3.na.sdi.amiller_v_vista.DDCControl proxy;
```

in page load method i am calling the web method as follows

```
proxy = new DDCControl();

Guid y = new Guid("45a5b1c2-2fa5-4136-abdd-bc213b694848");

DataList1.DataSource = proxy.GetAllDDCs(this.AccountID, y);

DataList1.DataBind();
```

I am getting the following error:

> An invalid data source is being used for DataList1. A valid data source must implement either IListSource or IEnumerable

```
public DDCReturnGetAll GetAllDDCs(Guid accountId, Guid authToken);
```

the return type of GetAllDDCs is DDCReturnGetAll

where

```
public class DDCReturnGetAll : DDCReturnBase 

{ public DDCReturnGetAll(); 

public DDCInfo2[] DDCs { get; set; } }
```

where

DDCInfo2 is

```
public class DDCInfo2 { public DDCInfo2(); 

public BrandingType brandingType { get; set; } 

public string ChargebackName { get; set; } 

public string CollectorName { get; set; } 

public string Description { get; set; } 

public string URL { get; set; } }
```

Can you please help me with this issue?

Comment: What is the type returned by GetAllDDCs? Look in the Object Browser window to see what it returns on the client. Also tell us what it returns on the server.

Comment: Can you show a portion of the code for DDCControl?

Comment: the return type of GetAllDDCs is DDCReturnGetAll where   
public class DDCReturnGetAll : DDCReturnBase 
{ 
public DDCReturnGetAll(); 
public DDCInfo2[] DDCs { get; set; } 
} 
where DDCInfo2 is 
public class DDCInfo2 { 
public DDCInfo2(); 
public BrandingType brandingType { get; set; } 
public string ChargebackName { get; set; } 
public string CollectorName { get; set; } 
public string Description { get; set; } 
public string URL { get; set; } }

Answer (score 2):

The object returned from GetAllDDCs doesn't implement IListSource or IEnumerable. Most likely the object returned has a property on it that you should bind to instead.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to look at the return type from the procy.GetAllDDCs method and see what it is returning.

The error message you are getting shows that the DataList1 control cannot find a way to enumerate the items for binding.